# Subtitles for Windows Media Player

Tags: windows, vb.net, label, windows-media-player

I'm working on a simple video player which will search videos on the Internet and will play them. I'm planning to download the subtitles (some videosharing sites, such is YouTube, support this feature) and display them in my Windows Media Player-based form.

But it seems that WMP doesn't support subtitles. There are some workarounds for this, such is using VobSub, but this won't work as I play the video directly from the Internet (and searching&downloading subtitles may take a while, so I can't add them while the video will be played). So I'm trying to show a label over the WMP Control, but I can't make it transparent (only it's background, of course).

So I'm asking for solutions. What could I do to solve this issue? Thank you

Comment: Who told you WMP doesn't support subtitles? You just place a .srt or .sub file in the same directory as the movie and make it have the same basename and it is automatically picked up.

Comment: Well, this doesn't help me, as I will play streams from internet... Anyway, I thought that WMP can show subtitles only via filters, such is VobSub

Comment: you may combine video and subtitles using this 
<br>http://superuser.com/questions/520510/combining-video-and-subtitle-files-as-one-video answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been very long, but I am also working on a solution for this there is a transparency key setup in VB which I am using similar to your idea. It will all be transparent except a label will be on top to show the subtitle. I have made the label and am now making a subtitle reader.

What you do is firstly make the form borderless, then go to form properties and select transparency key to a certain color and then pick the same color for the form background. It will make the form background transparent and any control that is using the same color transparent as well.

Edit:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

'Setting Transperency Key
Me.TransparencyKey = Color.Aqua

'Setting Form Background color to transperency key
Me.BackColor = Me.TransparencyKey

'Making form borderless to make it completely transperent 
'but this will also result in being unable to move the form
Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None

End Sub
```